# URL rewrite path to send as variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm not sure if this is possible and if it is, I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have a url, for example www.example.com/john

What I want to do is use a rewrite rule for this to become www.example.com/index.php?name=john

Is this possible? And if so, what rewrite rule(s) would I need to put in .htaccess

Many thanks in advance

John

Comment: Where is your research? please do not expect stack users to do the research for you. However, If I were you, I would look into regex-replace functions and how to use regex. regexr.com is a good place to learn regex

Comment: Hi, thanks for the supportive advice. I have searched the site and internet for this information but I have to admit, this is an area that I have very little knowledge of as I rarely have the need to use htaccess rewrite rules. I am not asking someone to do the research for me - if anyone knows then all I'm asking is if they could point me in the right direction or share what they know already. I wouldn't ask for someone to trawl and report for me - that's just rude.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue, so if anyone else is looking for something similar, here is what I used.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```